# C# count number of parameters in query

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want to run an insert query in C#, which has multiple parameters. I just want to have a `for loop`, so that it goes through all parameters and assign a value to that parameter.

Query is in access database.

```
    public static bool SubmitData(string queryName)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(cnnString);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryName, conn);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        string strParameterName;

        conn.Open();
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryName, conn);

        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = queryName;

        for (int i = 0; i < cmd.Parameters.Count; i++)
        {

        }

        conn = null;
        return true;

    }
```

Above example has 3 parameters, but count is coming up as 0.

Answer (score 4):

I really fail to see where are the three parameters.  `Parameters.Count` **does not** return the number of parameters your procedure receiver. It returns the count for the already added parameters.

---

What you probably want is:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.Type1).Value = value1;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.Type2).Value = value2;
```

`Parameters` is the parameter collection, initially empty. The method `Add`, add the parameter, and  the Value property assign it's value.

Note that in `OleDbConnection`, the order of the parameter matters, so you need to know before hand the order from the query.

Comment: I agree; nowhere do I see where he adds these parameters.

Comment: parameters are in in the query in access database.

Comment: cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryName, conn);

queryname is an insert query and has three parameters. i want to pass value to these parameters, not sure how to do this

Comment: I have made the changes, added parameters to the code, but it is not writing back to the database. queryName is an insert query in the database. cmd.Parameters.Add("[strSource]", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "APL";

Comment: Try to post your whole method and the query too